# Adding data to form before it submits via Javascript in Django

Tags: javascript, html, django, forms

I am working on an app in Django where the user puts in their address and submits it in a form. I need to get this form data, along with its corresponding lat/long, into the views and save it in a model. So, I have used Javascript to call a lat/long API before the form submits and then add that data to the form so all of the data (the address and the lat/long) gets submitted to the server. However, this newly inserted data by Javascript does not show up with the rest of the POST data when submitted. I am not sure why this is.

Here is the JS code:

```js
const initiate_ride_form = document.querySelector("#initiate-ride-form");
    if (initiate_ride_form != null) {
        
        document.querySelector("#start-ride-button").onclick = () => {
            
            // these are just predecided addresses to simplify the code and isolate this problem
            const origin = '20%20W%2034th%20St%2C%20New%20York%2C%20NY%2010001'
            const destination = '1600%20Pennsylvania%Avenue%20NW%2C%20Washington%2C%20DC%2020500';
            
            fetch(`https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=${origin}&key=b45938af46624365b08b989268e79d5e`)
            // Put response into json form
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                
                // get the lat and long and save them in variables
                console.log(data.results[0].geometry);
                const longitude_origin = data.results[0].geometry.lng;
                const latitude_origin = data.results[0].geometry.lat;
                
                // add the make the hidden input's value equal to the long
                var input_long_origin = document.querySelector("#from_long");
                input_long_origin.value = longitude_origin;
                
                // add the make the hidden input's value equal to the lat
                var input_lat_origin = document.querySelector("#from_lat");
                input_lat_origin.value = latitude_origin;
            });

            // submit form, ideally with the newly inserted data
            initiate_ride_form.submit();
        }
        
    }
```

Here is my HTML form:

```html
<form method="post" id="initiate-ride-form" action="{% url 'initiate_ride' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="hidden" name="from_lat" id="from_lat"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="from_long" id="from_long"/>
</form>
```

So, I tried to add the lat and long that I retrieved from the outside API as the value of the already created hidden input. Then, I wanted to submit the form so it has all the data I needed.

However, when I submit the form, the POST data looks like this:
[POST Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2piy5.png). The values just show up as empty strings.

I have logged the updated form in the console and the lat long data does get added to the input field's values. It just doesn't get submitted via POST.

Can anyone help me with this problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: The `submit()` call needs to be within the fetch callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment but untested. The actual call to submit the form should be within the callback once all the other processing has been done as by the very nature of asynchronous operations the response may come sometime after the calling function has finished.

```
const initiate_ride_form = document.querySelector("#initiate-ride-form");
if( initiate_ride_form != null ) {
    
    document.querySelector("#start-ride-button").onclick = () => {
        
        const origin = '20%20W%2034th%20St%2C%20New%20York%2C%20NY%2010001'
        const destination = '1600%20Pennsylvania%Avenue%20NW%2C%20Washington%2C%20DC%2020500';
        
        fetch( `https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=${origin}&key=b45938af46624365b08b989268e79d5e` )
            .then(r => r.json())
            .then(data => {
                document.querySelector("#from_long").value = data.results[0].geometry.lng;
                document.querySelector("#from_lat").value = data.results[0].geometry.lat;

                // MOVE the submit() call here within the callback
                initiate_ride_form.submit();
            });
    }
}
```